# How to integrate Dart into a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dart, dart-pub

How should I go about integrating my Dart application, into my rails application.
I'm having a hard time with the whole, 'packages' structure that has to exist on every directory.

Because the subdirectories reference the root using an alias, rails is not serving them even though all of this is in the 'public' folder

Comment: Do you basically have different Dart classes pertaining to different controllers? Are you using the Asset Pipeline?

Comment: No I simply want to serve my dart application, from within my rails application. However because dart creates a 'packages' symbolic link in every directory you create, when it goes to load a file those symbolic links are invalid from rails

Answer (score 7):

Excuse me for reviving, but you may try https://github.com/m0gg/dart-rails

It's targeting to simplifiy usage of Dart in Rails applications with automatic dart2js and pulling in dependencies by pub with a rake-task.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `pub build --mode=debug` the build directory contains the application without symlinks.
The Dart code should be retained when `--mode=debug` is used.

Here is some discussion going on about this topic too [Dart and it's place in Rails Assets Pipeline](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!searchin/misc/rails/misc/jWStJXC0qm8/GhhadxcHSCgJ)

Comment: While that's helpful, it really doesn't solve the issue of developing a Dart application within a rails environment. This only works if your Dart application lives in a bubble, and doesn't have to interact with the surrounding environment (such as making ajax calls or interacting with the HTML)